# Как узнать о готовности сервера Windows к работе

Tags: windows, windows-service

Как узнать, что все службы запускаемые на сервере с Windows 2008 запустились и сервер готов к работе?

Comment: Служба готова - можно пользоваться службой, независимо от того загрузились другие или нет ещё. Какой смысл ждать загрузки ещё чего-то, когда то что надо уже работает? Тем более когда службы по своим функциям ну вообще никак не пересекаются.

Comment: вообще-то некоторые службы зависят одна от другой.

Comment: Хочется иметь что-то в духе оповещения, мол все службы запустились.

Comment: @айтишник И что это меняет для независимых служб? Да и зависимые подождут какие им нужны и заработают, не дожидаясь остальных? Так?

Comment: @Sergey. так. но дальнейшее обсуждение таких деталей не имеет прямого отношения к вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ниже изложенное не относится к методам get но, возможно, каким-то образом поможет:

такой код в командной строке

```
sc query type= service state= all > srvsaall
```

запишет состояние всех служб в файл **srvsaall**.

такой

```
sc query type= service state= inactive > srvsaoff
```

запишет в файл srvsaoff все неактивные службы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не поверите, но никак! Я серьёзно!

Всё дело в том, что у некоторых служб стоит настройка отложенного запуска, а некоторые запускаются только по запросу. ОС никак не информирует о завершении процесса запуска всех служб.

Пойдём дальше. Что значит "сервер готов к работе". К какой? К обмену файлами - одна служба. К DNS - другая служба. К интерактивной сессии - третья. Ко всем какие только возможны - когда захочет. Какой-нибудь сервис вполне может запуститься только когда к нему потребуется  обращение.

Более того, такая задача в принципе возникать не должна. Вряд ли Вам нужно знать, что запустилось всё, что только можно. Достаточно знать только, что запустилось то, что Вам надо.

Comment: >>Достаточно знать только, что запустилось то, что Вам надо.
Сложно?

Comment: @Krusty Да вообще-то не особо сложно... Проверить состояние нужной службы достаточно просто. Как конкретно - зависит от используемых инструментов.